# Empty data return after PHP AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

I don't get any data alert after using the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.autosuggest').keyup(function() {
        var search_term = $(this) .attr('value');
        $.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });

    });
});
```

And using the following PHP code

```
<?php
include('system/includes/db_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['search_term']) == true && empty($_POST['search_term']) == false) {

    $search_term = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['search_term']);
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT username FROM promoties WHERE username LIKE '$search_term%'");
    while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) !== false) {
        echo '<li>', $row['username'], '</li>';
    }
}
?>
```

If I put 'test' in the alert, it just works fine, but if I alert the data, it gives an empty alert box.

I also tested the PHP code on it's own, and it works perfectly..

What's wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Before arguing about your potential SQL injection problems. Did you try setting explicitly set the `dataType` to `"html"` as in `$.post('search.php', {search_term:search_term}, function(data) { ... }, "html");`?

Comment: Try to test `echo $_POST['search_term']` in the beginning of PHP file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your `.autosugest` is an input(which i think it is)... you need to get its value by

replace this

```
var search_term = $(this) .attr('value');
```

by

```
var search_term = $(this) .val();
```

`attr()` is not needed here

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Solved the problem!

Answer (score 1):

```
Use simple falsy value check.

if(isset($_POST['search_term']) && !empty($_POST['search_term'])) {
         // code here
}
```

Or
   Write some echo before the for loop. this will test with your query is executing or not.